# Media queries behaving weirdly around breakpoint

Tags: css, media-queries

I've been trying to create some responsive hiding classes in CSS, only to realize that my `@media` queries are behaving very weirdly around breakpoints.

#### What I want to create

I want to create two classes, that have the following functionality:

- `.hidden-sm` should be hidden when the viewport width is **less than 768px**
- `.hidden-md` should be hidden when the viewport width is **greater than or equal to 768px**

#### What I have tried so far

My original solution was the following:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .hidden-sm { display: none !important; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1279px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  .hidden-md { display: none !important; }
}
```

However, this code ends up showing both `.hidden-sm` and `.hidden-md` (or hiding none of them if you prefer) **at exactly 768px**.

Another thing I tried was this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .hidden-sm { display: none !important; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1279px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  .hidden-md { display: none !important; }
}
```

But this one ended up hiding both `.hidden-sm` and `.hidden-md` **at exactly 768px**.

I think I have a pretty decent grasp of `@media` queries, but this specific problem is confusing to me. I would appreciate a working solution, as well as an explanation of why these solutions don't work as expected.

**P.S.** *I know `!important` is not the best practice, but I think it's quite necessary for my specific needs, which might not be obvious in this example.*

**Update:** For whatever odd reason, if I change the first piece of code to `768px` and `769px` respectively, it works, only the breakpoint is one pixel after the desired one. Why?

Comment: on the second one, why not just use a min width of 769px?

Comment: @AndyHolmes I want the `.hidden-md` to be hidden when the width of the screen is `768px`.

Comment: You have 2 queries that are fighting for the same pixel, in that case make the first one's max width 767 and you'll sort your troubles

Comment: @AndyHolmes That is the first code sample I provided, which is what I thought. However, it does not work for god knows what reason. Apart from that, setting to `767px` and `768px` didn't work, but `768px` and `769px` works. Why?

Comment: You first solution looks ok --> https://jsfiddle.net/h9sby3ro/1/

Comment: @AngelosChalaris sorry so it is, make sure you aren't zoomed in on your browser. Your code in theory works fine

Comment: @ovokuro Apparently, it is not. Testing the exact fiddle you posted on `767px` shows both lines of content.

Comment: @AndyHolmes You mean this could be a browser problem? I have a weird-ish DPI on this computer, let me check on my laptop and get back to you... If this is a browser/DPI/display bug, I have to admit I did not see that one coming.

Comment: It's possible, caught me out once (zooming, not pixel density)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really replicate your issue so I've rewritten the media queries in a simple format to check that the logic works.

I'm not using a max width and a min width, just using one (as it's all that's needed in most cases)

```css
@media(max-width: 767px){
    body {
        background-color: red;
    }
}

@media(min-width: 768px){
    body {
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

Which can also be tested here - https://jsfiddle.net/3dLyhr8c/

The fact this works across my devices I can only assume that you have an issue with your browser zoom or similar :)

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to test this and provide a working solution. Turns out this is browser/environment-specific and that the media queries worked just fine.

Comment: No problem at all, at least you know now :)